# what is the use of ready method in Ember.Application? Will it be called after all the views are initialized?

Tags: ember.js

what is the use of ready method in Ember.Application? Will it be called after all the views are initialized? Otherwise is there any handle i can get from ember which gives callback after all views are initialized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Ember.Application#ready` will fire after DOM ready and your application has been initialized.

What problem are you trying to solve that you'd like to have a callback after all views have been initialized?

`Ember.View#didInsertElement` will tell you when a specific view has been inserted into the DOM.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i want to get a callback when ember completes processing of all the views. So that i can have view instances to work on.

Comment: Can you be more specific about why you'd want that?

Comment: i have some javascript code to be executed which expects a view to be present. Like displaying login dialog if the user is not logged in. But if I call the function inline, it is not showing up as ember didnot process the view yet. Using timeout as workaround for this.

Comment: That sounds like a bad workaround. Having a callback for when all views have been initialized isn't the right solution it seems either. Sounds like your other code should be triggered upon the rendering of one of the specific views that the code relates to.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Will be moving the code to didInsertElement. What if the code depends on two views?

Comment: You can use a parent view's didInsertElement in that case?